# Is there a shortcut to close a View in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to Close a View in Eclipse (not <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the editor)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can define your own key binding: `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys`.

Search for `Close Part` and use the binding `Ctrl+W`. In the `When` dropdown select `In Windows`. Then you can also close Views by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Comment: Is the conflict with Ctrl+W for "Close" (close the active editor) an problem?

Comment: I have tested the above and observed no problems. If eclipse cannot resolve the conflict there will be a pop up at the bottom right where the user can select the operation which should be executed.

Comment: really helpful as we use extended eclipse it was Ctrl+F4 for me

Comment: @Ralph The *Close* (close the active editor) commands can be unbound. The *Close Part* command works for editors also. (It's a bit weird.)

Answer (score 9):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to open the system menu, and then press <kbd>C</kbd> to close the view.

Comment: I'm running Eclipse version `2021-06 (4.20.0)` on Linux and there's no `Close` option in the menu, only "Detach". However, binding `Ctrl+W` to `Close Part` in Preferences - Keys work just fine.