# remove search highlighting via keyboard shortcut in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

After doing a Java or File search in Eclipse, the (purple) highlighting of matches in files persists indefinitely, distracting me from whatever task I try to accomplish after I complete my search.

I know that I can open the Search view (by pressing Alt+Shift+Q,S, or by clicking its icon) and then click the "Remove All Matches" button that looks like an advertisement for Dos Equis, but I get tired of all this view-activating and clicking.

I want to clear search results in Eclipse using just the keyboard.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. Keep on Pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> when reach **search view**. Release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key.

Close search view(in fact any view) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731640/is-there-a-shortcut-to-close-an-view-in-eclispe)

Once search view is removed from the current perspective search highlight will be removed automatically. If you want to see it again then open search view.

Comment: I just tried this on Eclipse 4.3, and closing Search did not remove the search highlights in the editor.

Comment: Its is working on my machine. Please update your post with screenshots or add more details

Comment: Indeed, it does seem to work. I think I was closing the view the wrong way (I may have been pressing ESC) but when I use the "Close Part" command it does indeed remove search highlighting. BTW I found it easier to activate the Search view by pressing Alt+Shift+Q,S.

Comment: Eclipse 4.4, W7.  Closing the Search view does not remove highlighting for me.  This problem is extra-annoying since there don't seem to be an action to bind a keyboard shortcut to.  This solution has way too many keypresses to be useful.

Comment: @jordanpg Yeah, it's not working consistently for me, either, and I can't tell whether the behavior is intended. I'll keep looking for a more robust mechanism.