# Eclipse toggle show/hide panels

Tags: eclipse, toggle, keyboard-shortcuts, panel, show-hide

Is there a way to show/hide various panels in Eclipse?

For example, shift-alt-p opens the Package Explorer panel in my setup, but then to close the panel I have to mouse over and close it manually.

Ideally one could toggle show/hide panels in Eclipse with keyboard shortcuts set via prefs > general > keys

Tough on the wrist to go keyboard-mouse-keyboard-mouse all day.

Perhaps I'm missing some magic combo, please enlighten if you have the Nirvana to spare.

Comment: My advice is not to toggle them.

Comment: You can use Ctrl+M to maximize the current editor - Ctrl+M to restore everything again.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, but that's not quite it, I'd like to close the panel, not reduce it to its non-maximized state. Probably not possible without hacking the source I suspect, but want to put this out there in the event that there was a quick & dirty solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731640/is-there-a-shortcut-to-close-an-view-in-eclispe ?

Comment: @atlanto thanks, giving Chandrayya the nod as I was unable to find an SO thread that covered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> you will get below pop up.

[image]

Traverse or cycle through the views you want to close by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> key. After selecting the view to be closed in the above pop up release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. 
Then the view to be closed will be activated.

Go to `Window->Preferences` type **keys** in the search box. Check whether any short cut key is assigned to **close part**. Refer below picture,

[image]

In my case it is assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. Once the view is activated press this short cut key to close the view. If any short cut key is not assigned to **close part** then you can assign new short-cut key for this.

Click on **Binding** text box(Refer second picture) and assign your own short cut key.

Comment: +100 Chandrayya, hugely helpful, my wrist thanks you ;-)